# await CurrentApp.LoadListingInformationAsync() never returns

Tags: c#, windows, windows-store-apps, uwp, win-universal-app

I have an app published in Windows Store for quite some time and recently through some users I came to know that the price of the IAP items is not being displayed in non-US regions, upon investigation I found that this call never returns in non-US region and works fine when the store region is US.

`var productListing = await CurrentApp.LoadListingInformationAsync();`

In recent times I have not edited or re-published the IAPs in the store. This issue is causing monetary loss for me in non-US regions.

Comment: Thanks for reporting this issue, I have reported it to the related team. I will post it here once there is any update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay. I was able to look at, and debug your issue. It seems there is a problem with the product document. It is missing key pieces of data. Unfortunately, you cannot fix it yourself. The correct team is aware of the issue and working on a fix.  It will be corrected shortly. Sorry for the problems and thank you for letting us know!

Comment: Thanks a lot for going an extra mile here. Really appreciate it. Can you please let me know once it is fixed?

Comment: Okay! This has been fixed! It should work fine now. Once, again, sorry about that!

Comment: Affirmative! The issue has been fixed. Can you provide some details on what data was missing and how it got into that state?